# Proof verification $\overline{f(M)}=f(X)$

Tags: real-analysis, solution-verification

Let $f:(X,d)\rightarrow (Y,\rho ) $ be continuous and $M\subset X $ with $\overline{M}=X$ prove  $\overline{f(M)}=f(X)$

My solution:

$f(M)\subset f(X)\Rightarrow \overline{f(M)}\subseteq f(X)$

now let  $x\in f(X)$ because $\overline{M}=X$
$ \exists $ $(x_{n})\subseteq M$, $x_{n}\rightarrow x\in X$

$f$ is cont $\Rightarrow$ $f(x_{n})\rightarrow f(x)\in\overline{f(M)}$

because $f(x_{n})\in f(M)$ $\Rightarrow$ $f(x)\in\overline{f(M)}$

is my solution ok?

Comment: Just a correction: $x\in f(X)\iff\exists y\in X$ such that $x=f(y)$. Then $\exists(x_n)_n$ st $x_n\to y$.

Comment: There is probably a typo in "now let $x\in f(X) ....$. Should be "now let $x \in X$". Otherwise, proof is fine.